# Yii2 active record filter equal value in colums

Tags: yii2

The picture below is my sample database and I want to query record which do not have the same `date_received` as `date_released` and `time_received` as `time_released`.

[image]

The following MySQL query works exactly what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM `dts_track` where  date_received != date_released and time_received != time_released
```

This is my Yii2 active record query so far, but it returns all records from the database:

```
$unit_received = \common\models\dts\DtsTrack::find()->where(['!=', 'dts_track.date_received', 'dts_track.date_released'])->andWhere(['!=', 'dts_track.time_received', 'dts_track.time_released']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using array syntax for `!=` condition, third element of array is treated as value, so it will be escaped as a value. So you're actually creating conditions like `date_received != 'date_released'` - comparing to static string instead of column value. You should either use [`yii\db\Expression()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression):

```
$unit_received = \common\models\dts\DtsTrack::find()
    ->where(['!=', 'dts_track.date_received', new Expression('dts_track.date_released')])
    ->andWhere(['!=', 'dts_track.time_received', new Expression('dts_track.time_released')]);
```

Or avoid array syntax completely:

```
$unit_received = \common\models\dts\DtsTrack::find()
    ->where('date_received != date_released')
    ->andWhere('time_received != time_released');
```